# Vmware 9 bridged wireless adapter with WAP2?

Tags: vmware-workstation, wireless-bridge, wpa2

I've been trying to figure out how to setup my guests so they can bridge with my wireless card and use WPA2. I currently have it setup so that Vnet0 is set to use just the wireless card and Vnet1 bridged with the Ethernet.

The issue is all the guests view both adapters as an Ethernet connection instead of the wireless bridge with the wireless card as a wireless adapter. Because of this I'm unable to set WPA2 information for when it bridges using the wireless network. Does VMware workstation pass all adapters as Ethernet connections? Is there a solution out there that can work around this issue?

Edit: I was able to confirm that when I connect to a wireless network that is open the DHCP information gets set. It's only when I try to connect to a WPA2 network both ASE and PSK Enterprise and Personal that it doesn't get the DHCP.

Comment: Connect to the wireless network before starting your virtual machines.

Comment: I have, the machines still wont connect to the network and get an IP. When I bridge over the Ethernet they get assigned an IP and everything works just fine.

Comment: You should probably seek help at our sister site [su], as this question really isn't on topic here. Though I have heard that bridging virtual machines to a wireless NIC can be finicky or non-functional...

Comment: Thanks I was debating which one to post this topic in. Is it possible for me to move it or suggest to move it over to SU?

Comment: Yes, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

You could share the internet connection between your host wireless adapter and any virtual adapter (which all VMs will use in VMWare, and make sure DHCP from VMWare is off for the VMnet you will take) in the Network Connections menu and you will only have to connect to the wireless network from the host OS.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't understand this but from what it sounds like you're suggesting I set up a bridge between my wireless card and the Vnet I want to act as a bridge in vmware? This seems like a messy way to do it but could possibly work if there is no other way.

Comment: It would be the same thing to plug a Switch in a wireless bridge. The only difference is that it's software rather than hardware.